# MarkLogic Search API - How to do sort-order on same element as searchable-expression

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am attempting to do a search on a specific element so I have a searchable-expression within my options. I also want to sort by the values of this element so I have created an element range index on the value element. Here are my search options which hopefully makes things clear:

```
 <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <term>
            <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        </term>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <searchable-expression>/summary/name/value</searchable-expression>
        <sort-order type="xs:string" direction="ascending">
          <element ns="" name="value"/>
          <annotation>options for search institutions by name</annotation>
        </sort-order>
</options>
```

The problem is that when it does the sort it adds another value node (Taken from search:report id="SEARCH-FLWOR")

```
...order by xs:string(($result//value)[1]) ascending return $result)[1 to 50]
```

Instead of:

```
...order by xs:string(($result)[1]) ascending return $result)[1 to 50]
```

How do I prevent it doing this? I cannot change the searchable expression as the "name" element has another child element which I do not wish to search across. I also I can not leave the sort-order element name blank or set it to current node. It seems this would be simple, but I have not found anything to get this working.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<name>` as the target element of the searchable expression, but then restrict the query to only look inside `<value>` by adding an `<additional-query>`:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <term>
            <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        </term>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <searchable-expression>/summary/name</searchable-expression>
        <additional-query>
          <cts:element-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
            <cts:element>value</cts:element>
            <cts:and-query/>
          </cts:element-query>
        </additional-query>
        <sort-order type="xs:string" direction="ascending">
          <element ns="" name="value"/>
          <annotation>options for search institutions by name</annotation>
        </sort-order>
</options>
```

Comment: Using an additional-query seems to get the job done. Thanks for the suggestion.